# You have requested a non-existent service "jms_serializer"

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to use [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) but the service isn't listed after run `app/console container:debug | grep jms_serializer`

```
$ app/console container:debug | grep jms_serializer
jms_serializer.json_deserialization_visitor   container JMS\SerializerBundle\Serializer\JsonDeserializationVisit
jms_serializer.json_serialization_visitor     container JMS\SerializerBundle\Serializer\JsonSerializationVisitor
jms_serializer.metadata.lazy_loading_driver   container Metadata\Driver\LazyLoadingDriver
jms_serializer.metadata_driver                container Metadata\Driver\DriverChain
jms_serializer.naming_strategy                container JMS\SerializerBundle\Serializer\Naming\CacheNamingStrate
jms_serializer.xml_deserialization_visitor    container JMS\SerializerBundle\Serializer\XmlDeserializationVisito
jms_serializer.xml_serialization_visitor      container JMS\SerializerBundle\Serializer\XmlSerializationVisitor
jms_serializer.yaml_serialization_visitor     container JMS\SerializerBundle\Serializer\YamlSerializationVisitor
```

after install

```
composer require jms/serializer-bundle
```

and configure

```
// in AppKernel::registerBundles()
$bundles = array(
    // ...
    new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
    // ...
);
```

if thy to use in some place

```
$this->get('jms_serializer')
```

I get the error `You have requested a non-existent service "jms_serializer".`

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the service is serializer. You should just use the following.

```
$this->get('serializer');
```

Comment: `serializer` is just an alias for `jms_serializer` as can clearly be seen when running `bin/console debug:container | grep serializer`

Answer (score 0):

The bundle was installed but not enabled automatically in bundles.php. Had to enable it manually.

Enabling JMSSerializerBundle :

```
JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

Accessing the service :

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
```

Symfony 4.4